# Given some string and index, find longest repeated string

Tags: python, string-matching

I apologize if this question has been answered elsewhere on this site, but I have searched for a while and have not found a similar question. For some slight context, I am working with RNA sequences.

Without diving into the Bio aspect, my question boils down to this:

Given a string and an index/position, I want to find the largest matching substring based on that position.

For example:

#### Input

```
string = "fsalstackoverflowwqiovmnrflofmnastackovsnv"
position = 13 # the f in the substring 'stackoverflow'
```

#### Desired Output

```
rflo
```

So basically, despite 'stackov' being the longest repeated substring within the string, I only want the largest repeated substring based on the index given.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

#### Edit

I appreciate the answers provided thus far. However, I intentionally made position equal to 13 in order to show that I want to search and expand on either side of the starting position, not just to the right.

Answer (score 0):

We iteratively check longer and longer substrings starting at position `position` simply checking if they occur in the remaining string using the `in` keyword. `j` is the length of the substring that we currently test, which is `string[index:index+j]` and `longest` keeps track of the longest substring seen so far. We can break as soon as the sequence starting at `position` does not occur anymore with the current length `j`

```
string = "fsalstackoverflowwqiovmnrflofmnastackovsnv"
position = 13
index=position-1
longest=0
for j in range(1, (len(string)-index)//2):
    if string[index:index+j] in string[index+j:]:
        longest=j
    else:
        break
print(longest)
print(string[index:index+longest])
```

Output:

```
4
rflo
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I regret not making it more clear in the initial post, but I did intentionally set position to 13 in order to show that the substring can expand on either side of the starting position.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score -1):

Use the `in` keyword to check for presence in the remainder of the string, like this:

```
string = "fsalstackoverflowwqiovmnrflofmnastackovsnv"
# Python string indices start at 0
position = 12

for sub_len in range(1, len(string) - position):
    # Simply check if the string is present in the remainder of the string
    sub_string = string[position:position + sub_len]
    if sub_string in string[position + sub_len:] or sub_string in string[0:position]:
        continue
    break
# The last iteration of the loop did not return any occurrences, print the longest match
print(string[position:position + sub_len - 1])
```

Output:

```
rflo
```

If you set `position = 32`, this returns `stackov`, showing how it searches from the beginning as well.

Comment: Would a similar approach be taken if I wanted to check on either side of the starting position?

Comment: @PanchoVilla78 Yes, I updated the answer to reflect a suggested way to do that.